Why am I getting a Scala Extractor Compile Error?
I'm ramping up on Scala and following a tutorial about extractors. i.e. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_extractors.htm
object ExtractDemo {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val x = ExtractDemo(5)
      println(x)

      x match {
         case ExtractDemo(num) => println(x+" is bigger two times than "+num)
         
         //unapply is invoked
         case _ => println("i cannot calculate")
      }
   }
   def apply(x: Int) = x*2
   def unapply(z: Int): Option[Int] = if (z%2==0) Some(z/2) else None
}

But this code does not compile. i.e.
scala ExtractorDemo.scala
ExtractorDemo.scala:3: error: not found: value ExtractDemo
      val x = ExtractDemo(5)
              ^
ExtractorDemo.scala:7: error: not found: value ExtractDemo
         case ExtractDemo(num) => println(x+" is bigger two times than "+num)
              ^

Why can't it recognise the ExtractorDemo?

Scala is a compiled language. You should compile your code before run it
$ ls
ExtractorDemo.scala
$ scalac ExtractorDemo.scala 
$ ls
ExtractDemo.class  ExtractDemo$.class  ExtractorDemo.scala
$ scala ExtractDemo
10
10 is bigger two times than 5

Your code works both in Scala 3.3.3 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/eBbnjceQQXWHz0ewNpoVbg/2 and Scala 2.13.13 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/eBbnjceQQXWHz0ewNpoVbg
Please see Getting Started.

Interesting. I had used scalac, followed by scala in other examples. But eventually I realised that I could shortcut this and just use scala by itself. i.e. To test changes, etc. Good to know about this limitation.
